# How to create the 3D Image using php?

Tags: java, php, image, 3d, rendering

I have a .stl file from which I have extracted the data. Now I want to draw / render the image of the object in that .stl file. Please guide me how I draw / render 3D image in php.

As I have seen that the same can be achieved easily from Java 3D but my application is in php.

Comment: Jeez, you don't want much do you?

Comment: PHP doesn't come with any 3D libraries although you could probably implement something like OpenGL via C or use GD to generate a 2D image based on the file but it would be a lot of work.

Comment: You could try putting your vertex data into WebGL.

Comment: How is this not a real question? Huh!

Answer (score 1):

Just found a 3D library for PHP here http://kore-nordmann.de/projects/image_3d/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not impossible... although it is a little odd.

You can use [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library and render your stl into a png. You will have to implement all the 3D drawing stuff by hand (polygons, textures, lights, removal of unseen polygons).

Not an easy job.